# How to request a response as JSON in Rails from a browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to test the JSON response from a Rails controller GET action using only a browser.

If the url to the resource is `http://localhost:3000/models/action`, how do I tell rails to return the response as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple once you figure out how to do it.

You can specify the type of the response by adding the type as an extension to the action.

For example, if we want the json response, could alter the request to be `http://localhost:3000/models/action.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in the controller the respond format:

```
def action 
   @objects = Model.all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
   end
end
```

OR as a shorcut

```
def action 
   @objects = Model.all
   respond_to :html, :json
end
```

OR handle the format at controller level

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html, :json

   def action
     @objects = Model.all
     respond_with(@objects)
  end
end
```

And now when you are calling `http://localhost:3000/models/action.json` the response will be JSON format